# JQuery add CSS on click function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer, windows-rt

I have issue with IE on Windows RT devices(tablets). I have menu and submenus under it. If menu section has submenu then it has class "multi-level" and "inner-link". On proper desktop devices submenus are displayed when "hover","active", "selected", which on other browser on the same Windows RT device are trated as click on menu option to display submenu. However IE is not that friendly on that.

So I did this solution, which prevents default action on menu option click(that on click in IE lands to first page of submenu selections) and then added onclick CSS "display !important" to display submenu, which are under  tag with classes "list" and "lvl-2".

However this solution works partialy, it prevents default on click for IE+touch, but does not add CSS to needed elements on the same click.

My code:

```
$(function ieTouch() {

    var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
    var msie = ua.indexOf("MSIE ");
    var ifTouch = ua.indexOf("Touch");

    if ((msie != 0 || !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./))&& ifTouch != -1) {      // If Internet Explorer and touchscreen
        $(".multi-level .inner-link").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault ? e.preventDefault() : event.returnValue = false;
            $(e.currentTarget).find("ul.list.lvl-2").css("display", "block", "important");
        });
    }    
});
```

Thank in forward for any help.

Comment: Is your initial *if* statement definitely resolving `true`?

Comment: please try to log msie, !!navigator.userAgent.match and ifTouch.. are you sure that the if is actually true?

Comment: `.css("display", "block", "important")` `css()` method doesn't accept a third argument

Comment: Hello, yes it is true, I have had alert in it(also in click function) for half a day and removed before posting here. :)

Comment: A. Wolff - well I tried also using .css("display", "block !important") and css("display","block"). Same result :/

Comment: Are you sure setting block is what you really need? Is the currentTarget the correct thing? Why are you not adding a class instead?

Comment: Hello, actually I went for toggle class and restructured the code little bit, so now with few lines of jquery it is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `e.currentTarget.style.setProperty('display' 'block', 'important');` might be the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

`jQuery` does not support priority in css... you need to use pure `javascript` for it.

```
$.each($(e.currentTarget).find("ul.list.lvl-2"),function(el){
    $(el).get(0).style.setProperty('display','block', 'important');
};
```